# AjaxFileUpload in SharePoint 2013 Custom WebPart Access is Denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm having issue making use of AjaxControlToolkit's AjaxFileUpload works on a custom SP2013 WebPart.

When I tried to upload any files, I will always encountered the error below.

> SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

Further probing I find out is a

> 403 (Forbidden)
>
> Uncaught error raising upload complete event and start new upload

On Chrome, it will show uploaded 100% and followed by the error. Whereas on IE 11 it will show uploaded 0% followed by the error.

Below are the codes that I have.

WebPart.ascx

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=15.1.1.100, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:AjaxFileUpload runat="server" ID="fu" OnUploadComplete="fu_UploadComplete" />
```

WebPart.ascx.cs

```
protected void fu_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
        Log.Debug(e.FileName, "e.FileName", Location);
}
```

Web.Config in the WFE Server

> @ System.Web

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*POST" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit, Version=15.1.1.100, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" />
  <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2014.2.724.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" verb="*" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
```

> @ System.WebServer

```
<handlers>
  <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="POST" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit, Version=15.1.1.100, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" />
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2014.2.724.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" />
  ...
</handlers>
```

As well as

```
<location path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>  
</location>
```

As you can see, I tried using Telerik's RadAsyncUpload and able to make it work but sadly it doesn't support IE 11 which is the requirement that I have.

I'm suspecting it is due to permission issue to the temp directory that the files are first uploaded to before posting back to the codebehind. But I'm not sure where is the location. I've tried giving full control to the SP App Pool account and in the whole freaking D drive and still encounter this issue.